# jQuery Mobile External Panel lags on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2
According to the spec I am using an external slide panel as per http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-external/

What is happening is when the menu closes part of it lags behind so it doesn't close smoothly.

Hard to explain so I have an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sidouglas/GHh3S/1/

Open the left menu panel, and then click the `lorem ipsum` text to close the panel.

Simple implementation of the open close behaviour as per the documentation:

```
( function($) {

$(document).on("pageinit", function() {
            $("body>[data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin(); 
});

} ) ( jQuery );
```

Simplified DOM:

```
    <header data-role="header" id="header" data-id="header" class="header ui-page-theme- ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
            <ul class="ui-grid-b">
                <li class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="#main_menu" data-transition="reveal" class="f-menu menu_control ui-link ui-btn"><span>Open left panel</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="ui-block-b"><a href="#">logo</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-c"><a href="#">something else</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section data-role="page" id="product_details" data-title="category page" data-url="product_details" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" style="position: relative; min-height: 1045px;">
        <div class="ui-panel-wrapper ui-panel-animate ui-panel-page-content-position-left ui-panel-page-content-display-reveal ui-panel-page-content-open">
            <div role="main" class="ui-content single_product">
                Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra gravida. Etiam vehicula urna vel turpis. Suspendisse sagittis ante a urna. Morbi a est quis orci consequat rutrum. Nullam egestas feugiat felis. Integer adipiscing semper ligula. Nunc molestie, nisl sit amet cursus convallis, sapien lectus pretium metus, vitae pretium enim wisi id lectus. Donec vestibulum. Etiam vel nibh. Nulla facilisi. Mauris pharetra. Donec augue. Fusce ultrices, neque id dignissim ultrices, tellus mauris dictum elit, vel lacinia enim metus eu nunc.
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!--/mneu=-->
    <div data-display="reveal" data-position="left" data-role="panel" data-theme="a" id="main_menu" data-id="main_menu" class="main_menu ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-reveal ui-body-a ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open">
        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
           <li>blah</li>
           <li>blah</li>
           <li>blah</li>
        </ul><!-- submenu -->
        <!--/.catnav-->
    </div>
```

Hmm can anyone spot my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your markup before enhancement? markup above is wrong and is causing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/GHh3S/2/

Answer (score 0):

`<header data-role="header" id="header" data-id="header" class="header"  data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">`

I compared your working version Omar and the header declaration wasn't correct. Thanks.